# Wordpress website duplicating the content and putting it above the menu bar

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I was changing the theme on my wordpress website, and when i activated the new theme it entirely changed the placement of text. The text in the body of the website was moved into the header, above the navigation links. Picture of my problem:

[image]

I have no idea what has caused this to happen and would appreciate any help

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

I found that the content is in the `<head/>`. looks like "dev" code too me or a plugin conflict.  What theme is this?  below you can see the html thats in the head:

[image]

Comment: The theme is "Red Modern". I have tried getting into the header but i cannot find where the text is being put into it. The same issue is happening on each page.

Comment: is this a custom theme development for you? if not where can i find the theme?

Comment: http://bazahoteli.pl/

The theme was a default one available from within Wordpress but is it available to download from here

Answer (score 0):

1. Kindly go widgets and check if the contents of the widget moved up to the header
2. If not, check if there is any page builder plugin like **elementor** or **wp bakery**. If yes kindly try disabling the plugins.
3. If the above two points doesn't work, check if the contents from posts moved to the header and check theme settings for the same.